# readHTMLTables -- Retrieving Country Names and urls of articles related to the heads of governments

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'd like to make a map of the actual world presidents.

For this, I want to scrape the images of each president from wikipedia.

The first step is getting data from the wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government

I have trouble getting the country names and president page urls because the table has rowspans.

For the moment, my code looks like below but it's not ok because of the row spanning..

```
    library(XML)    
    u = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government"
    doc = htmlParse(u)
    tb = getNodeSet(doc, "//table")[[3]]

    stateNames <- readHTMLTable(tb)$State
    presidentUrls <- xpathSApply(tb, "//table/tr/td[2]/a[2]/@href")
```

Any idea welcome!

Mat

Answer (score 0):

If there is heterogeneity in the table, I don't think we can deal with the problem by a single line of code. In your case, some `td` has `colspan=2`, while the others don't. So they can be selected and processed separately with filters like the following:

```
    nations1 <- xpathSApply(tb, "//table/tr[td[@colspan='2']]/td[1]/a/text()")
    nations2 <- xpathSApply(tb, "//table/tr[count(td)=3]/td[1]/a/text()")
```

Should you meet other types of conditions in the table, just keep in mind that XPath has more.